# Remove tag relation from product

Tags: product, tags

How can I programatically remove a tag relation from a product?

I have the following function that creates a tag relation, which is working well.

```
public function setTag($product, $tag){

    $store_id = Mage_Core_Model_App::DISTRO_STORE_ID;

    $tagRelationModel = Mage::getModel('tag/tag_relation');

    $tagRelationModel->setStoreId($store_id)
                     ->setProductId($product->getId())
                     ->setActive('1')
                     ->setCreatedAt( $tagRelationModel->getResource()->formatDate(time()) );

    $tagRelationModel->setTagId($tag->getId());

    $tag->saveRelation($product->getId(), null, $store_id);
}
```

How would I achieve the reverse of this?

Answer (score 1):

There is a method `deactivate()` in `Mage_Tag_Model_Tag_Relation` and I think you should use this.

So a function which looks like below may work in your case.

```
/**
 * Use to unsert a tag relation
 *
 * @param  Mage_Tag_Model_Tag $tag
 * @return Your_Class
 */
public function unsetTag($tag)
{
    $tagId = $tag->getTagId();
    $customerId = $tag->getCustomerId();

    $tagRelation = Mage::getModel('tag/tag_relation');
    $tagRelation->_getResource()->deactivate($tagId, $customerId);

    return $this;
}
```